# Excel printing worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-office-2019

I have a worksheet I work on and when I print pages on one computer the page setup is 100%, but on a different computer the page setup has to be changed to 94% to fit all the data on the page. Why is this and how do I fix it ?

Comment: Same operating system?  Same printer driver?  Same Printer?

Comment: No they're all different

Comment: There's your answer right there

Answer (score 3):

While the paper **size** might be equal between your different printers, the overwhelming majority of printers can't print to the full page, but only to the **printable area**. This is due to the fact, that the mechanics of a typical printer need some part of the page to grab it and move it through the printing apparatus.

When you scale a worksheet in Excel to fit the page, you actually scale it to fit the **printable area** of that page on the selected printer. With different printers providing different printable areas, a different scaling might be applied.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @ForwardEd let me add, that the **logical printable area** (what the OS sees as printable area) is not only a property of the printer, but also of the printer driver. The **physical printable area** (The mechanical limit of the printing mechanism) is a property of the printer and can be bigger than the logical one.

Comment: Just to tack on a small tid bit.  Even from the same computer printing to the same printer with the same paper, but using a different printer driver you can wind up with two different printable areas.

Comment: @ForwardEd Good catch! The printable area is not only a property of the printer, but also of the printer driver. Edited my answer.